# How do I get the website to look the same after clicking a link and coming back?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am filtering products by color/size on a page with a list of products, using `<select onchange="myFunction()">.`

The filtering works fine, but if a user clicks a product and is moved to the product page, then clicks the browser back button, the select box shows the right color/sizes but the list is not filtered. The user would have to select a different color/size and then the same color/size again to see the correct list (or I'd add a Filter button).

Is there any way to make sure the user gets the filtered list right away when using the back button?
Ideally, I would not like the myFunction() to run again, as that might cause the user to have to scroll down, but rather just have the site look the same way it did before clicking the link.

Comment: @Nino's answer below is the way I'd go, except that I'd use `id` in the elements and not use `querySelector`.
You'd have to go over all elements that the user can change and read and set from `localStorage` and save to it on each element's change.

Comment: You can experiment with `localStorage.body=escape(document.body.innerHTML)` and `document.body.innerHTML=unescape(localStorage.body)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can persist values across refreshes/naviagation by using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), by doing something like this:

```html
<select onchange="onSelectChange">
```

```js
// when the user selects a value, save it
const onSelectChange = event => {
  localStorage.selectValue = event.target.value;
}

// when the user navigates to the page, if there is a saved value, set it
if (localStorage.selectValue) {
  document.querySelector('select').value = localStorage.selectValue;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that if someone filters the page today, then closes the window and comes back two days later, the page would still be filtered?

Comment: Right.  Except that `querySelector` and not `id`... - my opinion.  I respect yours.